# How to use iText7 to parse HTML into a list of elements than can be added to a PDF document while preserving styles?

Tags: java, html, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm using itext7-core version 7.2.5 along with html2pdf version 4.0.5 to implement the following functionality on my Java web application that is intended for PDF generation: The user inputs a string holding HTML code and specifies a rectangular area of the page where the HTML must be rendered.

I'm using the *HtmlConverter.convertToElements(htmlString)* method to create a variable of type List<IElement> that holds the list of all the elements that must be rendered into the canvas.

```
for (IElement element : elements){
    float padding = 5f;
    if (blockElement instanceof Paragraph){
        Paragraph p = (Paragraph) blockElement;

        // calculate the height of the Paragraph
        float marginTop = (p.getMarginTop() != null) ? p.getMarginTop().getValue() : 0;
        float marginBottom = (p.getMarginBottom() != null) ? p.getMarginBottom().getValue() : 0;
        float paddingTop = (p.getPaddingTop() != null) ? p.getPaddingTop().getValue() : 0;
        float paddingBottom = (p.getPaddingBottom() != null) ? p.getPaddingBottom().getValue() : 0;
        float height = marginTop + marginBottom + paddingTop + paddingBottom;

        // check if the currentYPosition has enough space for the new Paragraph
        if ((currentYPosition.getCurrentYPosition() - height) < htmlRectangle.getBottom()) {
            // add new page and reset the currentYPosition
            canvas = new Canvas(new PdfCanvas(pdfDocument.addNewPage()), htmlRectangle);
            currentYPosition.setCurrentYPosition(htmlRectangle.getTop());
        }

        canvas.showTextAligned(p, htmlRectangle.getLeft(), currentYPosition.getCurrentYPosition() - p.getMarginTop().getValue(), txtAlignment);
        currentYPosition.setCurrentYPosition(currentYPosition.getCurrentYPosition() - (height + padding));
    } else if (blockElement instanceof Div) {
        Div div = (Div) blockElement;
        ...
    } else if (blockElement instance of whatever){
        ...
    } ...
}
```

That works but has two major restrictions

- The styling of most of the elements is not preserved very well. For example <h1>Sample Heading</h1> is not rendered as a big blod text but is instead rendered as a small, almost plain, text.
- This approach involves a very long *else - if* chain to check for all possible HTML tags that the blockElement could be representing.

I understand that my use case is very restricted as I cannot use *HtmlConverter.convertToPdf* because that creates a new document, while what I want is to add a small piece of HTML to an existing document. And I also can't just use the Document.add((IBlockElement)element) method because I want the element to be added to a specific location on the canvas.

With that said, is there a better way to do this?